# Replacing Fragment in tab, changes all tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment, android-tabs

**EDIT**
I edited the previous question, wich i solved. Thanks a lot for the replies.

I have a gui with 3 tabs (News, Strategy and History), in one of them (News) i load an ExpandableListView and when the user clicks in one of the items from the list, it loads another fragment containg details from the selected item. I managed to replace the fragment in that tab with another fragment, using this code:

```
    CategoryTab categories = new CategoryTab();//Fragment 2
    FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(this.getId(), categories, "News");
    //transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, categories, "News");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

When the seconds fragment loads in the News tab, all the other tabs shows that fragment. I'm using this listener to manage tab navigation

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private final Bundle mArgs;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        this(activity, tag, clz, null);
    }

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {          
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My question is ¿why all the tabs shows the same fragment when the replacement is done? and ¿how can i simulate a back button with the icon provided in the action bar, to load again fragment 1 in News Tab?

Any help will be appreciated

PD: Sorry for my english

Comment: Try replacing `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` with `getActivity()` everywhere, such as when you set up your `IssueAdapter`.

Comment: You can always check if you getActivity() doesn't return null by calling isAdded() method in the fragment

Comment: I found the mistake, i was creating a new NewsTab Object somewhere in my code, thats why getActivity return null, thank you all for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call getActivity() in or after onActivityCreated, as before then it will return null.

The Fragment will be attached to a null activity until onActivityCreated... that is, if you call getActivity() in onCreate or onCreateView, it will return null because the Activity hasn't been created yet. So make sure you have all of your calls to getActivity() in or after onActivityCreated

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i'll do that and comment if it works.

Comment: I found the mistake, i was creating a new NewsTab Object somewhere in my code, thats why getActivity return null, thank you all for all the help.